# React toggle button after mapping through list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, dictionary

After getting results from api call to Google books i'd like to hide the description paragraphs and have a toggle button using the css class of hidden (tailwinds css). I'm currently just console.logging the elements on the "view description" button & I'm just not sure how to target a single element after looping through the nodeList with my toggleDesc() function

React SearchBar component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import axios from 'axios';

import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

import SearchResult from '../search-result/search-result.component';

const SearchBar = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [books, setBooks] = useState({ items: [] });
  
  useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchBooks() {
          const newRes = await fetch(`${API_URL}?q=${searchTerm}`);
          const json = await newRes.json();
          const setVis = Object.keys(json).map(item => ({
              ...item, isDescVisible: 'false'
          }))
          setBooks(setVis);
      }
      fetchBooks();
  }, []);

  const toggleDesc = (id) => {
    const newBooks = books.items.map(book => book.id === id ? {...book, isDescVisible: !book.isDescVisible} : book);
    console.log(newBooks);
    setBooks(newBooks);
}

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  let API_URL = `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes`;

  const fetchBooks = async () => {
    // Ajax call to API via axios
    const result = await axios.get(`${API_URL}?q=${searchTerm}`);

    setBooks(result.data);
    
  };

  // Handle submit
  const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    // prevent browser from refreshing
    e.preventDefault();
    // call fetch books async function
    fetchBooks();
  };

  // Handle enter press
  const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'Enter') {
          e.preventDefault();

          fetchBooks();

      }
  }


  return (
    <div className="search-bar p-8">
      <div className="bg-white flex items-center rounded-full shadow-xl">
        <input
          className="rounded-l-full w-full py-4 px-6 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none"
          id="search"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Try 'The Hunt For Red October by Tom Clancy' "
          onChange={onInputChange}
          value={searchTerm}
          onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
        />
        <div className="p-4">
          <button
            onClick={onSubmitHandler}
            className="bg-blue-800 text-white rounded-full p-2 hover:bg-blue-600 focus:outline-none w-12 h-12 flex items-center justify-center"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='result mt-8'>
      <ul>
         <SearchResult books={books} toggleDesc={toggleDesc} />
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

SearchResults Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { LazyLoadImage } from 'react-lazy-load-image-component';
import 'react-lazy-load-image-component/src/effects/blur.css';

import './search-result.styles.scss';

const SearchResult = ({ books, toggleDesc }) => {

  return (
    <div className="search-result mb-6">
      {books.items !== undefined &&
        books.items !== null &&
        books.items.map((book, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index} className="book-info mb-2">
              <li className="ml-4">
                <div className="flex">
                  <LazyLoadImage
                    className="book-img px-4 py-2"
                    effect="blur"
                    alt={`${book.volumeInfo.title} book`}
                    src={`http://books.google.com/books/content?id=${book.id}&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api`}
                  />
                  <div className="flex-1">
                    <h3 className="text-2xl">{book.volumeInfo.title}</h3>
                    <div>
                      <p className="flex">
                        <button
                          onClick={() => toggleDesc(book.id)}
                          className="bg-blue-800 mt-2 text-gray-200 rounded hover:bg-blue-400 px-4 py-3 text-sm focus:outline-none"
                          type="button"
                        >
                          View Description
                        </button>
                      </p>
                      {book.isDescVisible &&
                           <div
                           className="block border px-4 py-3 my-2 text-gray-700 desc-content"
                         >
                           <p>{book.volumeInfo.description}</p>
                         </div>
                      }
                    </div>
                    <h3 className="text-xl text-blue-800 mt-2 p-2">
                      Average time to read:{' '}
                    </h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
              </li>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchResult;
```

console

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add a property to each item of your books to handle the description visibility and change it when you click the button, this is a basic example

```
useEffect(()=> {
  fetch(url).then(res => {
    const newRes = res.map(item=> ({ ...item, isDescVisible: 'false' })) // <— add the new property to all items set to false
    setBooks(newRes);
  })
})
```

```
<p className='flex'>
  <button
     onClick={() => toggleDesc(book.id)} // <—- pass the id or the whole book
     className='bg-blue-800 mt-2 text-gray-200 rounded hover:bg-blue-400 px-4 py-3 text-sm focus:outline-none'
     type='button'
  >
    View Description
  </button>
</p>

//here show the desc according to the value of the property you added, no need for the hidden class
{book.isDescVisible && <div className='block border px-4 py-3 my-2 text-gray-700 desc-content'>
  <p>{book.volumeInfo.description}</p>
</div>}
```

This function needs to be on the parent where you are setting the state

```
const toggleDesc = (id) => {
  const newBooks = books.map(book => book.id === id ? {...book, isDescVisible: !book.isDescVisible} : book); <-- toggle the property
  setBooks(newBooks); <—- save it in the state again
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am able to change the property with the useEffect hook `useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchBooks() {
          const newRes = await fetch(`${API_URL}?q=${searchTerm}`);
          const json = await newRes.json();
          const setVis = Object.keys(json).map(item => ({
              ...item, isDescVisible: 'false'
          }))
          setBooks(setVis);
      }
      fetchBooks();
  }, []);` but it still seems to target all the books in the array when clicking one of the view description buttons

Comment: did you change your `toggleDesc` function?

Comment: Yes it's on the parent and I see when I click it does change the property correctly but logging the newBooks it shows them all. The dom changes to not showing any books.  `const toggleDesc = (id) => {
    const newBooks = books.items.map(book => book.id === id ? {...book, isDescVisible: !book.isDescVisible} : book);
    console.log(newBooks);
    setBooks(newBooks);
}`

Comment: Yes, it is ok for the console.log to print all the books, what you are doing is replacing all the array with a new one with the book you want the desc displayed changed, does that console.log display the book you want with the isDescVisible changed?

Comment: I see now. & yes the book clicked to view the description has the property of isDescVisible set to true but need to figure why the dom where the books are goes white after clicking the button. Could it be along the lines of the other books do not have the isDescVisible property or is that okay because they are set to false initially?

Comment: Could you update your question with your current code please? that way would be easy to help you :)

Comment: Just updated the question with current code. Appreciate the help

Comment: I see the problem now, your books state is an object with an array inside, this should solve the problem `setBooks({items: newBooks});`

Comment: Glad it worked, don't forget to mark the answer as correct ;)